# How to merge this two specific arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have this array:

```
$array['apples'][0]['name'] = 'Some apple';
$array['apples'][0]['price'] = 44;

$array['oranges'][0]['name'] = 'Some orange';
$array['oranges'][0]['price'] = 10;
```

How can I merge the two arrays so i get this:

```
$array[0]['name'] = 'Some apple';
$array[0]['price'] = 44;
$array[1]['name'] = 'Some orange';
$array[1]['price'] = 10;
```

Comment: Does "orange" and "apple" have the same number of items ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have PHP here to test, but isn't it just:

```
$array2 = $array['apples'];
array_merge($array2, $array['oranges']);
```

Granted, this is now in `$array2` rather than `$array`...

Comment: Tested and that works. Much simpler than what I was suggesting :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$second_array = array();

foreach($array as $fruit => $arr){
    foreach($arr as $a){
        $second_array[] = array("name" => $a["name"], "price" => $a["price"]);
    }
}
print_r($second_array);
```

Comment: It does now after your edit. But i'd rather use a built in function if possible :)

Comment: I don't think there is one for your specific array format. Not that I can think of off the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the values of `$array` are the arrays that you want to merge. Since this requires a dynamic number of arguments passed to array_merge, the only way I know to accomplish it is through `call_user_func_array`:

```
$array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_values($array));
```

That should work with any amount of fruit.